# Delphi error E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods or constructor

Tags: delphi, abstract

I'm a very old dog trying to learn a new trick. I've created a class that has two virtual abstract methods. When I create the subclass, I can use the virtual methods as well methods that call the abstract methods in the base class. The issue is, I need to also use methods in the base class that call the abstract method to be able to access a variable data source.

I've tried prefixing the non-abstracted method with the class name which cause the E2076 error. I've got similar code working great in C#, just can't seem to get Delphi to do what I want. The base class is below. The commented lines in procedure UseData_internal are what is causing the problem.

I don't consider this a duplicate of a previous question because the usage situation is different. Other methods within the base class need to be able to use the method that is virtual abstract.

```
unit UData;

interface
type
  TData = class
    private
    protected
      function ReadData_(loc: word): byte; virtual; abstract;
      procedure WriteData_(loc: word; val: byte); virtual; abstract;
    public
      function ReadData(loc: word): byte;
      procedure WriteData(loc: word; val: byte);
  end;

implementation

function TData.ReadData(loc: word): byte;
begin
  result := ReadData_(loc);
end;

procedure TData.WriteData(loc: word; val: byte);
begin
  WriteData_(loc, val);
end;

procedure UseData_internal;
var
  loc: word;
  val: byte;
begin
  loc := 100;
//  val := TData.ReadData(loc);
  val := val + 7;
//  TData.WriteData(loc, val);
end;

end.
```

Comment: The E2076 is caused because you are trying to access your class method without first creating the class.  Declare a variable in your UseData_internal procedure as `Data: TData;`, then create your class `Data := TData.create;'. Then call your function as `Data.ReadData(loc);`. I'm still confused why you have virtual / abstract methods and expect to call them in the base class, as that is not was abstract is used for..

Comment: Hi, The question that this has been redirected to does not answer the question in the way you have phrased it.  You have to instantiate the class to call the method, and you can use `Self.` to reference the object in one of its methods.  You can call an abstract method in a method of the base class.  `Self` is assumed by the compiler where possible, so you can just call `ReadData_(loc)` and `WriteData_(loc)`.  I would prefer to always use `Self.ReadData_(loc)` to be explicit about what I want to do - it's a habit I picked up over the years in other languages and makes the intent clear.

Comment: ReadData_ and WriteData_ as defined in the derived class define how data is accessed. This needs to be done outside the base class. There are many (almost 300) methods in the base class that need read/write access. UseData_Internal is just an example of a base class method needing to get/put data out correctly. As I said, this works fine in C# and even C++ so I don't see how this isn't the purpose of abstract. But, as I said old dog trying to learn new tricks.

Comment: @divecontx So your question is confusing.  I think you need to edit your question and show how your derived classes work so we can better understand how to help you.

Comment: Thank you John and Rob for your recommendations and not being condescending as I hear sometimes happens on  SO. Your comments pointed me to my problem of not having all desired methods in the base class. I have a new problem now that the issue questioned has been resolved but I need to research before I ask about it here.

Comment: It's not uncommon to have a base class where you want to override methods in derived classes. If there's no default behavior, then 'virtual; abstract;' is the way to go. If, however, you want to have some default behavior occur when a derived class does NOT override one of the methods, then it's just 'virtual;' and the 'abstract;' tag does not apply. (Abstract says you MUST override it.) So the design of the class isn't correct anyway since you likely don't need the methods with '_' at the end.

But the main answer is correct: you need to declare an instance of the class to call its methods.

Comment: The question written as-is is exact duplicate. In `UseData_internal` you are trying to call the method on a class instead of an instance. Going through comments, it turns out that you have slightly different problem, but your code example does not show what you want to do. If the `UseData_internal` is part of the derived class declaration, then you must show that. right now it is standalone function that seems unrelated to the `TData` class. Please provide proper [mcve] that will show to which class `UseData_internal` belongs and what is it relation to `TData`